# Firebase Anonymous Login fails after Xcode Update

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cocoapods, firebase-authentication

My anonymous login for Firebase was working for months; however, when Xcode forced me to install some updates, it couldn't find some pods. After deleting those pods after running pod update, the project will now build; however, while attempting the anonymous login, I get this error:

```
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
```

If I wait long enough, I get error messages like this:

```
[Client] Discarding message for event <private> because of too many unprocessed messages
```

Here is my login method:

```
func login(onCompletion: @escaping (NSError?) -> Void) {
    print("authenticating user")
    FIRAuth.auth()?.signInAnonymously(completion: { result, error in
        guard error == nil else {
            print("error while authenticating user")
            onCompletion(loginError)
            return
        }

        if let user = result {
            self.defaults.set(user.uid, forKey: "uid")
            onCompletion(nil)
        } else {
            onCompletion(loginError)
        }
    })
}
```

which is called in the root view controller's viewDidLoad.

Comment: Have you add <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/> in plist file

Comment: Yes, I have also added the exception domain firebaseio.com

Comment: can you share some demo with me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what the issue was, but it was specific to the project. I created a new project and pulled the code from github and now it works like normal.